# Is it safe to cast my 2D points to 3D points for a library which only takes Vector3s?

Tags: xna, vector, raycasting, linear-algebra

I need to cast a ray in 2D space for bullet collision detection, but the [Ray.Intersects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197628) method requires a [BoundingBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingbox) which uses vector3's not vector2's. My question is should I just ignore the Z value and pretend it's a vector2? Raycasting is already slow enough so I think having calculations done in an unnecessary 3rd deminsion should be eliminated even if the value is just 0, but I don't know.

So should I implement my own raycasting system maybe using [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) which is for 2 dimensions or should I go the cheap way and make a bounding box a bounding plane?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Bresenham's line algorithm is definitely not the same thing as a Ray-AABB intersection test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can just use Vector3's where the z-value is 0.

In geometry, any 2D point also exists in the 3rd dimension. In a 2D game, everything could be represented with Vector3s where the z-values are all identical. Often in a 2D game, you use the Z value as the *depth*, to draw a tree in the background (low Z value) or the main character in the foreground (higher Z value).